# Higher Order Functions or pass by reference?

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I'm confused over when I should be using Higher Order functions over using function references.

Consider the below:

Reference external function:

```
(+++) :: Int -> Int -> Int
(+++) a b = a + b

myFunction :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
myFunction (x : xs) (y : ys) = result : myFunction xs ys
     where
       result = x +++ y
```

Pass function as parameter:

```
(+++) :: Int -> Int -> Int
(+++) a b = a + b

myFunction :: [Int] -> [Int] -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> [Int] 
myFunction (x : xs) (y : ys) func = result : myFunction xs ys
    where
       result = func x y
```

What are the pros/cons of the different approaches?

**N.B.I am aware of the Prelude zipWith - this is purely for illustration**

Comment: If you think you will have some use for calling `myFunction` with something other than `(+++)` as the last argument, then passing as a parameter is the right thing. Otherwise, it is pointless.

Comment: I'm not sure if these can really be compared. It's like comparing `\x y -> x + y` and `\x -> x + 7`. The first one is strictly more general. The second one might be exactly what you want in a given context.

Comment: Passing a function as a parameter is required if you want to avoid specifying concrete implementation of that function and leave that when its been used. Were as if your function doesn't require any external dependencies passing function is of no point.

Comment: I think of this as largely the aesthetic/artistic aspect of coding -- how general do you make your definitions?  To me, there is a level of generally that "feels right" -- I'd say as general as possible before making things more general becomes unbearably complicated for the problem being solved, where bearability is also a felt sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that **by default**, you should hardcode all function calls. In this example, `myFunction` should just call `+++`.

However, I know of **three exceptions to this rule**:

1. Your code becomes clearer by not hardcoding the function call.
2. Your code uses the parametric version more than once with different parameters.
3. You have reason to believe that future code will use the parametric version more than once with different parameters.

Note that the "future code" in point 3 can mean your own code (you plan to add another module next week that uses the parametric version with a different parameter, so you already add the parametric version today) or somebody else's code (you export the parametric version in a library and you guess that the users of the library will want to call the parametric version with different parameters).

While points 1 and 2 are reasonably clear-cut, point 3 requires lots of guesswork about your future needs or the needs of other people. Consequently, there are different schools of thought as to how much your code today should be prepared to meet future needs. I guess that many Haskell programmers end up a bit more on the parametric side of things.